# Ionic firebase Login issue

Tags: android, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication

I have an ionic 1 application and I am getting a weird error on log in only on android. Only the first time when the user opens the application and logs in, It is logging perfectly. When he logs out and tries to log in again I am getting this error "Auth/Network-Request Failed" and cannot login unless he closes the application and reopens. I do not get whats the issue and why the first time it is working. This is my code.

```
<ion-content style="background-image:url(img/LoginBack.jpg); background-size:100% 100%;" ng-controller="LoginController">

    <hr style="height:100px; visibility:hidden">
        <div align="center">

            <img src="img/loggo.png" style="width:43%;height:13vh">

        </div>
<hr style="height:20px; visibility:hidden">
        <div align="center">
            <div style="width:100%;padding:5px 10px 5px 10px" align="center">
                <h5 class="button" style="color:white;min-height:12px;line-height:12px;background-color:#3b5998;width:100%;color:white;border-radius: 20px"
                 ng-click="FacebookLogin()">
             <div class="row" style="padding:0px">
                 <div class="col col-10" style="padding:3px 0 0 0">
                     <i class = "ion-social-facebook larger" style="margin-right:50px"> </i> 
                     </div>
                 <div class="col col-80" align="center" style="padding:0;line-height:35px">
                     Sign in with Facebook 
                 </div>
                  <div class="col col-20">

                     </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>

            </div>

        <div class="padding" style="width:100%;" align="center" ng-show="!toggle">
            <button style="min-height:35px;line-height:35px;width:100%;border-radius: 20px" class="button button-balanced small_button"
             ng-click="Switch()">
                Already have an account? Log in
            </button>

        </div>


        <div style="width:100%; padding:10px 10px 0 10px" ng-show="toggle">

            <div align="center" style="padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px">
                <input ng-model="registerusername" align="center" style="padding:20px;background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);padding-left:20px;color:#2ab041;border-radius:5px"
                 placeholder="Email" type="text" required>
                <br>
                <input align="center" ng-model="registerpassword" style="padding:20px;background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);padding-left:20px;color:#2ab041;border-radius:5px"
                 placeholder="Password" type="password" required>

            </div>

            <div class="col " style="background-color: transparent">

                <h6 style="margin:5px 0 10px 0;padding:0px;min-height:6vh;line-height:6vh;width:100%;border-radius: 20px" class="button button-balanced small_button"
                 ng-click="LogIn(user)">
                Sign in
            </h6>

            </div>
            <div class="col col-10" style="background-color: transparent">


            </div>
        </div>

        <div align="center">
            <h4 style="margin-top:-2px;padding-top:0px;font-weight:bold;color:white; font-size:15px">
                or
            </h4>

        <div class="padding" style="width:100%;" align="center">
            <button style="min-height:35px;line-height:35px;width:100%;border-radius:20px;background-color:white;color:#2ab041" class="button button-balanced small_button"
                 ng-click="GoToRegister()">
                Register with Email
            </button>

        </div>

            <div align="center">
                <h6 style="color:white" ng-click="GoToForgetPass()">
                    Forgot your password?
                </h6>
            </div>

        </div>
</ion-view>
```

//JS FILE
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword($scope.registerusername, $scope.registerpassword)
    .then(function (user){
        //GO HOMEPAGE
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        alert(errorCode);
    });

Comment: Firebase Auth uses `navigator.onLine` to detect network state. If this issue happens occasionally, it may be related to `navigator.onLine`. Try installing https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information which fixes the problems with `navigator.onLine`.

Answer (score 0):

did you use this method on signout?

```
firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
 // Sign-out successful.
}, function(error) {
 // An error happened.
});
```